# Node-red payload convertion for mysql node

Tags: mysql, node-red

How to convert a msg.payload like **12345,67890** into **"12345","67890"** ?

Basically I receive a payload with many values and need to pass them to a mysql node.

Thanks in advance.
Sep

Comment: Is the input a single line of CSV or is it multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact type of input there are a couple options

First the core CSV node will split a payload into either an array or an object (if the first line of multiple lines contains the column names).

Second if you just have a single input then you can break it up with a function node using the normal NodeJS/Javascript functions for working with Strings. e.g.

```
var chunks = msg.payload.split(',');
msg.payload = {};
msg.paylaod.first = chunks[0];
msg.payload.second = chunk[1];

return msg;
```

Comment: niceIn the meantime I soved it with a less elegant Change

Comment: You can always add your own solution as an answer as well